# chrisbanes - ActionBar-PullToRefresh consume touch

Tags: android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

I've implemented ChrisBanes' pull-to-refresh using a Stock Action Bar.

However, after the pull, the "Loading..." message appears and covers all my action bar buttons. This is great, and what I expect. However, if I touch the action bar where I know the buttons normally are, they behave just as if the buttons were there.

How can I get the 'loading...' actionbar header to consume all touch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the 'loading...' actionbar header to consume all touch
>   events?

The reason it doesn't to begin with is due to how the `View` is added to the `Window`. When [`PullToRefreshAttacher` creates the `WindowManager.LayoutParams`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/uk/co/senab/actionbarpulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshAttacher.java#L605) used for calling `WindowManager.addView(View, LayoutParams)`, it uses the flag:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
```

Which [as per the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE) indicates:

> Window flag: this window can never receive touch events.

So, if you want the header view to consume touch events, you'll have to modify the `PullToRefreshAttacher` and remove this flag.